# present progressive vs present perfect progressive

Tags: present-continuous, present-perfect-progressive

> 1. This week I am looking after my neighbor's cat.

This is a temporary situation, which is happening only this week, and I am emphasizing that fact.

> 2. This week I have been looking after my neighbor's cat.

I am looking back from the beginning of the week until now, which may be the middle or the end of the week. I am emphasizing duration.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I **am looking** after my neighbor's cat this week.

What you are doing  doing now. No reference to the past. Just like me, I'm explaining this to you now here but won't be as soon as I finish typing this answer.

2) I have been looking after my neighbor's cat this week.

In this sentence, you are not looking back. A better way to understand this is that **the week is still in progress** and the activity **began at some UNSPECIFIED point in the past**.

I've been answering questions re the SP and PP for some time now in this forum.
[I am still doing it and the time this began is unspecified as I write this.]

Comment: Are you sure you' re not looking back in the second sentence because you wrote " began at some unspecified point in the past  so you' re looking back . I agree with everything else

Comment: Looking back is confusing. The person making the utterance is specifying that something began in the past, but they are not "looking back". The person is just saying that the thing began at an undefined point in the past without specifying when. Compare that to: Last week, I looked after my neighbor's cat.